# React - "Unexpected token" when initialising state

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui

I'm fairly new to React, so please forgive any errors in this question!

I'm currently trying to get a basic login form working:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Input, Form, Button } from 'semantic-ui-react'

class LoginForm extends Component {

  state = { username: '', password: '' }

  handleChange = (e, { name, value }) => this.setState({ [name]: value })

  handleSignIn(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.props.onSignIn(this.username, this.password)
  }

  render() {
    const { username, password } = this.state

    return (
      <div className="login-container">
        <Form onSubmit={this.handleSignIn.bind(this)}>
          <Form.Field>
            <Input icon="user" iconPosition="left" placeholder="Username" type="text" ref="username" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
          </Form.Field>
          <Form.Field>
            <Input icon="user secret" iconPosition="left" placeholder="Password" type="password" ref="password" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
          </Form.Field>
          <Form.Field>
            <Button type="submit" className="inputSpacing" color="yellow"><Icon name='lock' />Login</Button>
          </Form.Field>
        </Form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default LoginForm;
```

The issue that I'm facing is that the `state = { username: '', password: '' }` line generates the following error:

`ERROR in ./react-client/src/components/coreComponents/loginForm.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: D:/path/to/project/react-client/src/components/coreComponents/loginForm.js: Unexpected token (6:8)`

I've copied this from [here](https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/form/#usage-clear-on-submit), but even the code snippets there give me this error. What am I missing? :(

Comment: Can you share us your .babelrc file?

Comment: Yeah, I skipped the error and jump to a quick conclusion in my answer. The problem might be class-fields proposal.

Comment: Take a look at [this issue](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/1402#issuecomment-356640678), seems to be the same problem

Comment: Yes, definitely it @Philippe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned on a similar [issue on github](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/1402#issuecomment-356640678). You should edit your **.babelrc** file to be able to use this syntax.

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["es2016"],
    "react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties"
  ]
}
```

Comment: This sounds like it could be the same issue. When using the solution from Ayan, the error just moved to the `handleChange` line, so I think you're right in saying I need to get my babel config set correctly. I can't see a babelrc file though....apparently it's because I installed with `create-react-app`

Comment: @mfisher91 that's because you want to use a specific syntax that needs a correct set up of babel. If you don't want to set up babel you can use the basic syntax like Ayan but you will have to bind your handleChange function like you did for handleSignIn

Answer (score 1):

Enclose it within a constructor. And also you need to bind your state to your component with **this** keyword

```
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      username: '', password: ''
    };
  }
```

Comment: This shouldn't be necessary if the proper `babel` plugin installed.

Comment: If I could have marked two answers as correct, this would be my second choice!

Answer (score 1):

You don't have `name` properties for your `Input`'s.

```
<Input name="username" icon="user" iconPosition="left" placeholder="Username" type="text" ref="username" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
<Input name="password" icon="user secret" iconPosition="left" placeholder="Password" type="password" ref="password" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
```

Comment: This answer was also correct - I needed to change `ref` to `name`. If you three combined your answers it would be perfect!

Comment: Yep, this was your second problem :) I hadn't read the error properly so I focused the input part. But the actual problem was different. Actually, answers should explain why you have this problem and how you can solve it. You are using a proposal in your code: "class fields". So, if you want to use it, you need a babel plugin. @Ayan's solution is just a workaround. You need to write your whole code according to regular syntax if you don't want to use this Babel plugin.