# create-react-app / babel / binding state and functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, create-react-app, eslint

Thank you for your time. I have the same issue as in [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51956481/react-unexpected-token-when-initialising-state/51957165) re parsing error - `unexpected token = eslint` on (originally state - which was fixed by putting in constructor, now) handleClick. New project and think this error will continue through the rest of the project.

```
class Header extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      activeItem: "home"
    };
  }
  
  handleClick = (event, { name }) => this.setState({ activeItem: name });
```

I am new to react, and apologise if this is a simple question. Project was installed with create-react-app, there is no babelrc file, the eslint is as follows.

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es2021: true,
    jest: true,
  },
  extends: ["plugin:react/recommended", "airbnb", "prettier"],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true,
    },
    ecmaVersion: 12,
    sourceType: "module",
  },
  plugins: ["react"],
  rules: {},
};
```

From what i have read, I have to install babel to the project, and customise the config to accept `state = { activeItem: "home" };` if I want to set state / functions outside the constructor and need to use a 'basic syntax', for fixing the function, i am not sure what that basic syntax is. Help?! I think the course of action is to create a babelrc config file, but am not sure why if it is already installed with create-react-app and do not want to install a bunch of dependencies unless i have to.

Thank you for your patience.

Comment: The Babel config that comes with CRA allows for class fields (and they're supported by all the browsers now anyway), so you should be able to use the field syntax `state = { activeItem: 'Home' }`. Is the error coming from ESLint or the webpack build?

Comment: the error is coming from eslint file (or at least says so in editor via squiggly line), project compiles, but has the error as it not rendering the component/s which are affected by this. The `state = { activeItem: 'Home' }` and this function can't be declared outside the constructor without the error showing.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to fix up your ESlint config a bit:

```
npm install eslint @babel/core @babel/eslint-parser --save-dev
```

and then add

```
parser: "@babel/eslint-parser",
```

to the top level of your ESLint config. Alternatively you could use the default Create React App ESLint config by removing yours, which should be all set already.