# 'Unexpected token =' error in eslint React

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I'm using `eslint` for my React project. I'm getting an error with something that must not have any errors. Check the comment in my code. Please let me know if something isn't clear.

```
    import React, {Component, createContext} from "react"

export const CurrencyContext = createContext()

class CurrencyContextProvider extends Component {

    // I'm getting an error here
    state = {
        selectedCurrency: 'USD'
    }
    setCurrency = (c)=>{
        this.setState({selectedCurrency: c})
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <CurrencyContext.Provider value={{...this.state, setCurrency: this.setCurrency}}>
                {this.props.children}
            </CurrencyContext.Provider>
        )
    }
}

CurrencyContextProvider.propTypes = {
    children: React.ReactNode
}

export default CurrencyContextProvider;
```

Comment: on which line is the error?

Comment: @gaitat It's where `state={` which shows a red-underline under `=`

Comment: this should prove helpful: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor

Comment: @gaitat I just created a constructor, but I'm now getting an error under the`=` in  `setCurrency = (c)=>{`. It's the same error

Comment: i don't get this error, which version of eslint are you running?

Comment: @MWO I'm running `eslint 7`

Comment: eslint from microsoft?

Comment: @MWO No, it's just the default eslint

Comment: Are you trying to instead a [static](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static) property? Can't really just assign a property in a plain es6 class like that. If you are trying to initialize state that would happen in the constructor.

Comment: @MWO Btw, I'm also using ecmaVersion 12

Comment: @asemshaat ah ok, you are using an npm package? im just using the vscode extension from microsoft

Comment: did you see this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/51957165/9175097

Comment: The latest answer posted by @MWO above seems to address this issue. Can you please confirm if that's the case? And if not, could you please include more details about how your code is transpiled? For example, what tools you are using, how are they configured, etc. It would also help if you could reproduce this issue on CodePen or a Git repository.

Comment: @npclaudiu Yes I already fixed that, it was my case